# Изображён — какой? Изображён — каким?

Tags: управление

Оба варианта имеют право на жизнь?

> В храме сохранился и его портрет – под тем самым знаменитым «Белым
>   ангелом». **Стефан Владислав изображён ведомый** за руку Богородицей **и**
>   **предстающий** перед Христом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

*В храме сохранился и его портрет – под тем самым знаменитым «Белым ангелом». **На нем Стефан Владислав, ведомый за руку Богородицей, предстает перед Христом**.*

Пояснение

1) Изображен **(каким?)** — практически используется **только Т.п.**  Изобразить — что? каким?

2)  *Стефан Владислав изображён **ведомым** за руку Богородицей и **предстающим** перед Христом.*

Такое **скопление слов** в форме Т.п. затрудняет прочтение текста.